# Which web frame of python has clicking button to pop a sub page's function?

Tags: python, python-3.x

Now I use python to design a page,I have not written python web code.
I want to know which python web frame encapsulates the functions I want.

For example,I have a button "dept" on my home page likes this:
[image]

I want to click this button "dept" to pop a sub page, and the sub page can choose the department likes this.

[image]

After selection, the home page can get the values of the selected departments in the sub page.

I know many HTML frame for example bootstrap's modal provides such a function.
So does python have such a function?

**The button "run" on my home page needs to use departments values as parameters to run python programs.**

So I should choose Django or Flask or Bottle?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your requirement can be served with simple javascript and HTML pages. The framework comes into picture when there are complexities in your project.

Let's say your application needs multiple API calls and needs a database then you have to use a framework. A simple HTML and js with Apache server are adequate, based on your requirement.

Since you have asked, let me explain the basic differences between those frameworks. Django is a well developed and tested framework. It will give 60-70% of predefined code to use in your project. We can use multiple applications or other libraries alongside Django or over Django. Coming to flask or bottle, they are microframeworks. In simple language, whatever was prebuilt in Django is to be customized and built separately in the flask.